# How to copy text to the clipboard when using Wayland?

Tags: clipboard, wayland

Is there a Wayland cli utility that copies text to clipboard?

I want to be able to do something like this:

```
echo "some" > clipboard
```

Something equivalent to xclip.

Comment: I'd be really interested to see the answer to this question too. From my usage of gnome-wayland, it seems to have many restrictions on clipboard access. For example,  if you copy something in program A and you close it, the clipboard will automatically get flushed. There is no restriction on copy to clipboard for xclip but it seems pasting will only work if you've copied something while in terminal but not anywhere else. on the other hand, ctrl-v/shift-ctrl-v has no restriction as long as original app is opened...

Comment: Discussion regarding wayland + clipboard - https://wiki.gnome.org/Initiatives/Wayland/PrimarySelection. According to this ticket it sounds like it's been implemented - https://github.com/swaywm/sway/issues/1012.

Comment: thanks for the links however that did not help me. maybe i missed something

Answer (score 46, accepted):

bugaevc's [wl-clipboard](https://github.com/bugaevc/wl-clipboard) are copy/paste utilities for Wayland:

> This project implements two little Wayland clipboard utilities,
> wl-copy and wl-paste, that let you easily copy data between the
> clipboard and Unix pipes, sockets, files and so on.
>
> Usage is as simple as:
>
> ```sh
> # copy a simple text message
> $ wl-copy Hello world!
>
> # copy the list of files in Downloads
> $ ls ~/Downloads | wl-copy
>
> # copy an image file
> $ wl-copy < ~/Pictures/photo.png
>
> # paste to a file
> $ wl-paste > clipboard.txt
>
> # grep each pasted word in file source.c
> $ for word in $(wl-paste); do grep $word source.c; done
>
> # copy the previous command
> $ wl-copy "!!"
>
> # replace the current selection with the list of types it's offered in
> $ wl-paste --list-types | wl-copy
> ```
>
> Although wl-copy and wl-paste are particularly optimized for plain
> text and other textual content formats, they fully support content of
> arbitrary MIME types. wl-copy automatically infers the type of the
> copied content by running xdg-mime(1) on it. wl-paste tries its best
> to pick a type to paste based on the list of offered MIME types and
> the extension of the file it's pasting into. If you're not satisfied
> with the type they pick or don't want to rely on this implicit type
> inference, you can explicitly specify the type to use with the --type
> option.

For all common linux-distributions the package-name is `wl-clipboard`, so use the command that suits yours (if not already installed):

```
sudo apt install wl-clipboard  # Debian
sudo dnf install wl-clipboard  # Fedora
sudo pacman -S wl-clipboard    # Arch linux
```

Comment: looks really cool! but i met with `src/meson.build:1:0: ERROR: Dependency "wayland-client" not found, tried pkgconfig and cmake` during install. I m sure its a stupid mistake from me. is it ? I have run `sudo dnf i meson -y` prior to the build attempt.

Comment: @mh-cbon On its github page it says:

`The only mandatory dependency is the wayland-client library (try package named wayland-devel or libwayland-dev).`

Maybe installing one of those mentioned packages helps? Alternatively, maybe the package can be found in the official package repositories.

Comment: it works perfectly after i installed `wayland-devel` package. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

[wclip](https://gitlab.com/j64wang/wclip) is a clipboard tool for Wayland that is very similar to `xclip`.

Usage is as follows:

`$ wclip i < my_text_file`

`$ wclip o
contents of my text file
$`

Disclaimer: I am the author.

Comment: As of Nov 2020, it seems the last commit was nearly 2 years ago. Is the project still alive?

Answer (score 0):

I've just '*converted*' to a Wayland UX, under Plasma (KDE) and so far most things are *as usual*.  The things important for my workflow have highlighted one or two underlying dependencies on X.Org.

Fortunately, I can use [`CopyQ`](https://copyq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command-line.html) as my Clipboard manager of choice.  [`CopyQ`](https://copyq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command-line.html) appears to be a very friendly Wayland supporter; so far, so good.

For CLI copy and paste I now use the following as `bash` `alias` commands:

`clip` ... Capture the current selection.

```
alias cliq='copyq selection'
alias clip='cliq; echo'
```

`paste` ... Emit current clipboard contents.

```
alias paste='copyq read '
```

[`CopyQ`](https://copyq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command-line.html) can be installed on [`flathub`](https://flathub.org/) from:

- [`CopyQ` page](https://flathub.org/en-GB/apps/com.github.hluk.copyq)

I've used CopyQ as soon as I installed my first Linux desktop.